# Chromium to Chrome on Linux

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, chromium

I'm on Ubuntu 11.04 and I'd like to move from Chromium to Google Chrome. Is there a way in which I could import my profile, plugins, history, etc. from Chromium to Chrome, so as to be able to "continue" from where I'm at in Chromium?

I'd really hate to have to go and install all of my plugins again as well as lose my cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where those settings are stored locally, but you could try syncing through a Google Account. Go to the Chromium settings and then "Private" (or whatever it is called - I only have access to the German version right now) and set up syncing with a Google Account. Then fire up Chrome and you should be able to load your data from that Google Account.

This is, however, only my idea of how this works. I have not tried this yet.

Comment: Works pretty well. Unfortunately, it doesn't sync extension preferences, so this is something to be aware of. It also won't copy over your cookies, so you'll have to re-login to all of your favorite sites.